# Custom component which displays voice recognition button if available

Tags: android, extend, android-edittext, voice-recognition, android-appwidget

I'd like to create a custom component which supports voice recognition. It will primarily be an extended EditText which should show the microphone button for voice recognition if it is available. I wanted to to look at the search app-widget on the homescreen but I don't find it in the source.

This is intended to use the voice recognition as some sort of dictation device, i.e. the user does not have to type but use his voice instead.

So could anyone please point me in some direction?
Thanks in advance,
Steff

Answer (score 0):

I think what u basically want to a button show/hide which can be controlled at the time of onCreate call. That should do ur work. Why would u need a component as such?

Comment: because it looks good ;) anyhow, do you know where I can find the original microphone icon?

Comment: I am not sure about what u mean by original. But if you want to take someone else's, u can try taking a screenshot of the same and using it. Try android example icons as well. A google too can get you the right icons